# SolidColorBrush problem in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, bing

I have problem with SolidColorBrush setting. I create polygon layer in bing map control in silverlight. When I set color as:

```
        Dim kocka As New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.MapPolygon()
        kocka.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)
```

everything is OK and polygon is displayed. But, when I use this approach (dynamic setting):

```
        Dim kocka As New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.MapPolygon()
        kocka.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 233, 14, 55))

        'OR: Color.FromArgb(CByte(0), CByte(233), CByte(14), CByte(55)))
```

the polygon is not displayed. What is wrong? I tried everything and nothing works.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter in Color.FromArgb is the Alpha channel (aka opacity). A value of 0 will make it fully transparent, so you should set it to something greater than 0 if you want to actually see the color. For instance:

```
kocka.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 233, 14, 55))
```

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) Wikipedia article for more information on ARGB colors.